# @hapi/lab with lab-transform-typescript is returning buggy code coverage results

Tags: node.js, typescript, unit-testing, hapi.js

I've got a HapiJS project in TypeScript and wanted to start adding some unit tests. Right now the code is very simple:

**server.ts**

```
import * as Hapi from "@hapi/hapi";
import routes from "./routes";

const server = new Hapi.Server({
    port: 80,
    host: "0.0.0.0",
    debug: {
        request: ["error"]
    }
});

let serverSetup = false;

const setupServer = async () =>
{
    if (serverSetup) return;

    await server.register([routes]);

    serverSetup = true;
};

export const init = async () =>
{
    await setupServer();
    await server.initialize();
    return server;
};

export const start = async () =>
{
    await setupServer();
    await server.start();
    console.log(`Server running at: ${server.info.uri}`);
    return server;
};
```

**routes.ts**:

```
import * as Hapi from "@hapi/hapi";

export default {
    name: "RouteIndex",
    version: "1.0.0",
    register: function (server:Hapi.Server, options:Hapi.ServerRegisterOptions)
    {

        server.route({
            method: "GET",
            path: "/",
            handler: (request, h) =>
            {
                return {message: "Hello, World!"};
            }
        });

        server.route({
            method: "*",
            path: "/{any*}",
            handler: (request, h) =>
            {
                return "404!";
            }
        });

    }
};
```

Then my unit test:

**server.test.js**

```
const Lab = require("@hapi/lab");
const { expect } = require("@hapi/code");
const { afterEach, beforeEach, describe, it } = exports.lab = Lab.script();
const { init, start } = require("../src/server");

const HTTP_PORT = 80;
const HTTP_STATUS_OK = 200;

describe("General Server Tests", () =>
{
    let server;

    beforeEach(async () =>
    {
        server = await init();
    });

    afterEach(async () =>
    {
        await server.stop();
    });

    it("Starts successfully", async () =>
    {
        server = await start();
        expect(server.type).to.equal("tcp");
        expect(server.settings.port).to.equal(HTTP_PORT);
        expect(server.settings.host).to.equal("0.0.0.0");
    });

    it("Responds to GET requests", async () =>
    {
        const res = await server.inject({
            method: "GET",
            url: "/"
        });
        expect(res.statusCode).to.equal(HTTP_STATUS_OK);
    });
});
```

To run my tests I have the following in my package.json:

```
{
    // ...
    "scripts": {
        // ...
        "test": "lab -vclS -T node_modules/lab-transform-typescript **/*.test.js",
        // ...
    }
    // ...
}
```

- The `-v` flag is added because I prefer verbose output
- The `-c` flag is added so I can get a code coverage report, and this is where my issue lies
- The `-l` flag had to be added because otherwise I was getting the error: `The following leaks were detected:__extends, __assign, __rest, __decorate, __param, __metadata, __awaiter, __generator,...` (all globals created by the TypeScript compiler)
- The `-S` flag was added per the [lab-transform-typescript documentation](https://github.com/garthk/lab-transform-typescript#readme) (`-S` == `--sourcemaps`)
- The `-T` flag is to load `lab-transform-typescript` (`-T` == `--transform`)

When I ran the tests, this was the result:

```
stevenbarnett@MacBook-Pro hapi-test % npm run test

> hapi-test@1.0.0 test /Users/stevenbarnett/Repos/hapi-test
> lab -vclS -T node_modules/lab-transform-typescript **/*.test.js

Server running at: http://0.0.0.0:80
General Server Tests
  ✔ 1) Starts successfully (4 ms)
  ✔ 2) Responds to GET requests (7 ms)


3 tests complete
Test duration: 111 ms
Coverage: 71.50% (61/214)
src/server.ts missing coverage from file(s):
        null on line(s): , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , 
src/routes.ts missing coverage from file(s):
        null on line(s): , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , 
        src/routes/index.ts on line(s): 24
```

So I get that `src/routes/index.ts` was missing coverage on line 24 (that's the 404 error, and I didn't test for a 404) -- but the other lines are nonsensical:

- `null on line(s): , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , ,`

Why is this happening, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I created a fork of HapiJS Lab to resolve my own problem here. My fork isn't **perfect** (it won't handle code that has multiple source files, like with concatenation) but it works fine for TypeScript processing.

Note that my changes were forked off of version 22.0.4 (commit `cd0bd3b1ad063ae62b58a764751fb3465a49fe99` specifically), so these changes may not work exactly on a newer version.

My first change was to `lib/coverage.js`:

```
         ret.source[num].hits = data.lines[num];
         ret.source[num].miss = isMiss;
     });
 
+    // Translate source maps
+    if (ret.sourcemaps)
+    {
+        const mappedSource = {};
+        const loadedOriginalSource = {};
+        Object.keys(ret.source).forEach(id =>
+        {
+            const line = ret.source[id];
+            if (line.originalFilename)
+            {
+                // ERROR: If a file came from two original source files (e.g. concatenation)
+                //        then we'll only include the first file in line.source and we'll
+                //        combine the number of hits
+                //
+                // Ideally this method needs a way to return more than one file and the files
+                // need to be merged by whoever reads the result
+                //
+                // Although for just TypeScript-to-JavaScript, this is fine
+                const originalSource = loadedOriginalSource[line.originalFilename] || Fs.readFileSync(line.originalFilename, 'utf8').split("\n");
+                loadedOriginalSource[line.originalFilename] = originalSource;
+                let originalLine = mappedSource[line.originalLine] || {
+                    source: originalSource[line.originalLine - 1],
+                    hits: 0,
+                    miss: false
+                };
+                originalLine.hits += (line.hits || 0);
+                originalLine.miss = originalLine.miss || line.miss;
+                mappedSource[line.originalLine] = originalLine;
+            }
+        });
+        ret.source = mappedSource;
+        ret.sloc = Object.keys(ret.source).length;
+        ret.hits = 0;
+        ret.misses = 0;
+        ret.sourcemaps = false;
+        Object.keys(ret.source).forEach(id =>
+        {
+            if (ret.source[id].miss)
+            {
+                ret.misses++;
+            }
+            else
+            {
+                ret.hits++;
+            }
+        });
+    }
+
     ret.percent = ret.hits / ret.sloc * 100;
     return ret;
 };
```

My second, and less important change, was to improve the output. I kept getting confused when I saw things like "2/127" and thought only 2 lines had code coverage when in fact 125 lines had code coverage. Also there was **no** output when 100% of lines had code coverage, which I didn't like - I like to see with certainty that I hit my goal. So I made the following change to `lib/reporters/console.js`:

```
     const coverage = notebook.coverage;
     if (coverage) {
         const status = coverage.percent.toFixed(2) + '%';
+        const outputColor = coverage.percent === 100 ? green : red;
         output += 'Coverage: ';
-        output += coverage.percent === 100 ? green(status) : red(status + ' (' + (coverage.sloc - coverage.hits) + '/' + coverage.sloc + ')');
+        output += outputColor(status + ' (' + coverage.hits + '/' + coverage.sloc + ' lines)');
         if (coverage.percent < 100) {
             for (const file of coverage.files) {
                 let missingLines;
```